# Redis / Get all keys & values from redis with prefix

Tags: redis

I store my data in redis. I store in one raw it guid, createday, and it size.

So I define the following:

```
var dbclient1 = db.createClient();
dbclient1.hmset("doc:3743-da23-dcdf-3213", "date", "2015-09-06 00:00:01", "size", "203")
dbclient1.zadd("cache", 32131, "37463-da23-dcdf-3213")
```

I wish to view all my files in my db. So I try the following:

```
dbclient1.hgetall("doc:*", function (err, res){
        console.log(err)
        console.log(res)
})
```

but res is `undefined`. How can I do it?

Comment: This GUI interface helped me out a lot when getting started: https://redislabs.com/blog/redisinsight-gui/ Not at all an answer to your question; but, great for viewing data, testing search, profiling, etc, so thought worth adding to this thread. There are other similar tools.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`HGETALL` returns all fields and values of the hash stored at key, you can't specify a mask: http://redis.io/commands/hgetall

You can call `KEYS doc:*` to get a list of all keys matching your criteria and then get all values in a loop.

However, an important note [per docs](http://redis.io/commands/keys):

> **Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care.** It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Comment: Don't use KEYS on production, it is too dangerous. Use SCAN instead, you have filtering WITH MATCH and cursor with COUNT - so it will be something like SCAN 0 COUNT 50 MATCH doc:*  http://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: @lcostea: using `KEYS` may or may not be dangerous depending on a particular scenario which OP didn't describe. Granted, `SCAN` is safer performance-wise, but since it's just a cursor it may not return all entries or return some entries multiple times, so must be used carefully as well.

Comment: @LiviuCostea Saying it's dangerous without giving a reason is not very helpful.

Comment: @StevenWade read the docs: http://redis.io/commands/keys there is a Warning there

Comment: Maybe this part is new. https://redis.io/commands/keys says: "Redis running on an entry level laptop can scan a 1 million key database in 40 milliseconds." -- which means the performance penalty might be a non-issue depending on your application.