# redis hmget with wildcard fields

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a hashset in redis like below.

```
"abcd" : {
    "rec.number.984567": "value1",
    "rec.number.973956": "value2",
    "rec.number.990024": "value3",
    "rec.number.910842": "value4",
    "rec.number.910856": "...",
    "other.abcd.efgh": "some value",
    "other.xyza.blah": "some other value"
    "..." : "...",
    "..." : "...",
    "..." : "...",
    "..." : "..."
}
```

if I call hgetall abcd, it will give me all fields in the hash.  My objective is to get only those fields of the hashset that begin with "rec.number".  When I call like

```
  redis-cli hmget "abcd" "rec.number*",
```

it gives me a result like

```
1)
```

Is there a way to retrieve data for only those keys which start with my expected pattern?  I want to retrieve only those keys because my dataset contains many other irrelevant fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis / Get all keys & values from redis with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728973/redis-get-all-keys-values-from-redis-with-prefix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget) do not supports wildcard in field name. You can use [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) for that:

```
HSCAN abcd 0 MATCH rec.number*
```

More about [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) function in [official docs](http://redis.io/commands/scan).

### LUA way

This script does it in LUA scripting:

```
local rawData = redis.call('HGETALL', KEYS[1]);
local ret = {};

for idx = 1, #rawData, 2 do
    if string.match(rawData[idx], ARGV[1]) then
       hashData[rawData[idx]] = rawData[idx + 1];
    end 
end
```

Nice intro about using `redis-cli`and LUA in Redis may be found in [A Guide for Redis Users](https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/).

Comment: In the Lua script, you should actually use `HSCAN` as well. If the Hash is big enough/RAM is tight, this will reduce the Lua engine's heap.